# Can't get positioning of these 3 images right

Tags: floats

I have three diagrams, trees, which I want to organise neatly. I want a and b to be beside each other, both consuming half the horizontal amount of space the c does. C should be underneath.

I also want the trees a and b to be vertically aligned i.e. the top of both are at the same level but also that their captions start at the same level.

This is doing my head in. At the moment I'm still struggling with the first task at hand. They're all just floating in a vertical column.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,arrows}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering

    \begin{subfigure} [t] {0.4\textwidth}

    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=3pt,auto,node distance=14mm,
    main node/.style={font=\sffamily},
    small node/.style={font=\sffamily,color={black!50} }]

    \node[main node] (12) {$(1,2)$};
    %
    \node[main node] (1) [below of=12] {$ (1) $};
    \node[small node] (2) [right of=1] {$ (2) $};

    \draw (12) edge (1) ;

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{3-simplex Voronoi Regions}
    \label{fig:3-simplex voronoi regions}

    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure} [t] {0.4\textwidth}

    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=3pt,auto,node distance=14mm,
    main node/.style={font=\sffamily},
    small node/.style={font=\sffamily,color={black!50} }]

    \node[main node] (123) {$ (1,2,3) $};
    %     
    \node[main node] (12) [below of=123] {$(1,2)$};
    \node[main node] (13) [right of=12] {$(1,3)$};
    \node[small node] (23) [right of=13] {$(2,3)$};
    %
    \node[main node] (1) [below of=12] {$ (1) $};
    \node[small node] (2) [right of=1] {$ (2) $};
    \node[small node] (3) [right of=2] {$ (3) $};

    \draw (123) edge (12) edge (13);
    \draw (12) edge (1);
    \draw (13) edge (1);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{2-simplex Voronoi Regions}
    \label{fig:2-simplex voronoi regions}

    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure} {\textwidth}

    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=3pt,auto,node distance=14mm,
    main node/.style={font=\sffamily},
    small node/.style={font=\sffamily,color={black!50} }]

    \node[main node] (1234) {$ (1,2,3,4) $};
    %
    \node[main node] (123) [below of=1234] {$ (1,2,3) $};
    \node[main node] (124) [right of=123] {$ (1,2,4) $};
    \node[main node] (134) [right of=124] {$ (1,3,4) $};
    \node[small node] (234) [right of=134] {$ (2,3,4) $};
    %     
    \node[main node] (12) [below of=123] {$(1,2)$};
    \node[main node] (13) [right of=12] {$(1,3)$};
    \node[main node] (14) [right of=13] {$(1,4)$};
    \node[small node] (23) [right of=14] {$(2,3)$};
    \node[small node] (24) [right of=23] {$(2,4)$};
    \node[small node] (34) [right of=24] {$(3,4)$};
    %
    \node[main node] (1) [below of=12] {$ (1) $};
    \node[small node] (2) [right of=1] {$ (2) $};
    \node[small node] (3) [right of=2] {$ (3) $};
    \node[small node] (4) [right of=3] {$ (4) $};

    \draw (1234) edge (123) edge (124) edge (134);
    \draw (123) edge (12) edge (13);
    \draw (124) edge (12) edge (14);
    \draw (134) edge (13) edge (14);
    \draw (12) edge (1);
    \draw (13) edge (1);
    \draw (14) edge (1);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{3-simplex Voronoi Regions}
    \label{fig:3-simplex voronoi regions}

    \end{subfigure}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: All those blank lines, at least the ones not inside a tikzpicture, cause paragraph breaks.  In particulra, the one between the two subfigures needs to be removed.

Comment: subfigures are positioned by the same code that positions letters, `xyz` would be horizontal, but if you put a blank line between them they would be vertical and if you do `xy<blank line>z` you get xy on one line and z below.